# Save image url in google place photo response

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, google-api

I am using the command :

```
drupal_http_request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference='.$term['photo_reference'].'&sensor=true&key='.$GOOGLEPLACESAPIKEY);
```

to get the image on browser its opening image, but i want to get the url of image to store in database ,can some please tell me how to do it.I tried `file_get_content()` but it also didn't worked.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to get the image saved or the url of image because the drupal_http_request is giving output which has variable data but its in random characters. File_get_contents is also not giving the value.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. You want the URL of an image? Where is this image? If you give more of an overview of what you are trying to achieve then it will be easier to suggest solutions.

Comment: SEE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37944572/saving-google-places-api-photos-to-my-server